# Gradle Property for "--continue" flag?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I need to be able to configure gradle to act as if it always had the "--continue" flag set using either "gradle.properties" or "init.gradle" in the root directory. Is this even possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a file `settings.gradle` and add

```
startParameter.continueOnFailure = true
```

Demo `build.gradle`

```
task t1 {
 doLast {
   throw new RuntimeException("fail")
 }
}

task t2 {
 doLast {
   println "ok"
 }
}
```

Without the above `settings.gradle`:

```
$ gradle t1 t2                                                                                                    
> Task :t1 FAILED
```

with the above `settings.gradle`:

```
$ gradle t1 t2
> Task :t1 FAILED

> Task :t2
ok
```

More info:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming I can do this in init.gradle, yes? It isn't a behavior that I want baked into the project; my intent is to provide a "template" of sorts that "developers" can copy into their environment and modify as needed, but that is ignored by GIT so that it doesn't affect CI/CD.